# Assign values to same variable using Getopt::Long

Tags: perl, getopt-long

I was trying to write a small perl script to understand `Getopt::Long`.

Below is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use Getopt::Long;

my $op_type = "";
my @q_users;

GetOptions (
  'query' => $op_type = "query",
  'create' => $op_type = "create",
  'modify' => $op_type = "modify",
  'delete' => $op_type = "delete",
  'user=s' => \@q_users
) or usage ("Invalid options.");

print "operation : $op_type\n";
```

When i ran this script as shown below:

```
$ ./all_opt.pl --query
operation : delete
```

I am assuming that am missing some kind of break statment in my program. I was expecting `operation : query` as the result.

Please let me know what i am missing here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were very close, but I think you slightly misread the [Getopt::Long documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Getopt::Long). Any code that you want to run when an option is found needs to be in a subroutine.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use Getopt::Long;

my $op_type = "";
my @q_users;

GetOptions (
  'query'  => sub { $op_type = 'query' },
  'create' => sub { $op_type = 'create' },
  'modify' => sub { $op_type = 'modify' },
  'delete' => sub { $op_type = 'delete' },
  'user=s' => \@q_users
) or usage ("Invalid options.");

print "operation : $op_type\n";
```

Note that I've just added `sub { ... }` around your existing `$op_type = '...'` code.

Comment: Thanks it worked. Yes i missed this part of the documentation.

Comment: @Fazlin the `sub { ... }` creates what we call a _code reference_ in Perl, or an _[anonymous function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function)_ or _lambda function_ in more general terms. It's basically _here is some code, you can run that when you want_. It does not get executed when those lines are encountered.

Answer (score 4):

**Explanation of what your code does**

You are misunderstanding the syntax. Let's add some parenthesis to clarify how Perl sees this code.

```
GetOptions(
  'query'  => ( $op_type = "query"  ),
  'create' => ( $op_type = "create" ),
  'modify' => ( $op_type = "modify" ),
  'delete' => ( $op_type = "delete" ),
  'user=s' => \@q_users
) or usage ("Invalid options.");
```

It will first run the assignment operations inside the parens. Each of those return the value that is assigned to `$op_type`.

```
$ perl -e 'print $foo = "bar"'
bar
```

Since all of them assign something to the same variable, the code is identical to this code.

```
GetOptions(
  'query'  => "query",
  'create' => "create",
  'modify' => "modify",
  'delete' => "delete",
  'user=s' => \@q_users
) or usage ("Invalid options.");
$op_type = "delete";
```

`GetOptions` wants you to pass references to variables so it can assign values to the variables for you. But you are doing that only for `user` with `\@q_users`. The rest of them is just strings.

In the end, you are printing the value of `$op_type`, which always has the value of the last assignment. As we saw above, that's *delete*. It cannot be anything else, because `GetOptions` never gets a reference to `$op_type`, so it cannot assign.